# How to initialize only a few elements of a global array in c++11 with gcc toolchain?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int array[10] = {
  [2] = 200,
  [5] = 500
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  std::cout << array[5];
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:6:1: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
 };
 ^
main.cpp:6:1: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
```

Is there any way to do this with g++? Clang works fine.

Comment: Sorry, edited the title.

Comment: I must say that the question is wrong unless learning C++11 specifically is one of your goals. The array you use will (probably) never become standard C++, but will probably remain a valid GCC VLA.

Comment: My goal is to know whether this is possible with the c++11 standard. That's all.

Comment: Oh, that's easy - no, nor with C++14, C++17 nor C++20.

Comment: found some open source code, which is compiling this with clang and c++11 standard. No worries. Thanks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There were plans to add it in c++20, but didn't went through.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes. Plans. Rejected, right?

Comment: Instead of doing C stuff - would you mind learning a different language, like C++?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Just wanted to mention that since you said it will probably never be standard; it might still be added one day

Answer (score 2):

That's a feature of C called designated initialisers and is not available in standard C++. So, while some compilers may allow it as an extension, it's not a feature of the language (hence not portable).

Now I don't know if your *actual* array will be more complex that that but, if not, you can do it with:

```
int array[10] = { 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 500 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other post have mentioned, the syntax you used for that array is from C, and not standard C++.

However, if you were declaring a large array in global, and you only want a to specify couple values, you can do:

```cpp
int array[500];

int main()
{
    array[2] = 200;
    array[5] = 500;
}
```

By declaring the array in global, it will be done in compile time, hence it will have all members initialized to `0`.

Comment: There's very little hope of getting OP:s `std::cout << "Hello World!\n";` code through a C compiler.

Comment: @Ted, I'm not sure I understand. This answer makes no mention of switching to a C compiler, just that designated initialisers are a C feature (much the same as my own answer). The suggestion in this answer works in both C and C++, albeit not with initialisation.

Comment: @paxdiablo You are correct. I made assumptions I shouldn't have made just because _my_ brain hurts when seeing this.